# Deleting specific a text string from a file using wildcards in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, wildcards

I am trying to delete a text string from a log file using wildcards in Notepad ++ but the selection always goes to the end of the line instead of the specific string.

Original Line:

```
11:04:42.011  moquery -c vlanCktEp  | egrep "^fabEncap|^dn|^encap |^excessiveTcnFlushCnt"
```

I want to delete `11:04:42.011` which has different characters as the lines increment.

This is what I an trying to get:

```
moquery -c vlanCktEp  | egrep "^fabEncap|^dn|^encap |^excessiveTcnFlushCnt"
```

Every combination I try wants to delete all the way to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+\s+`
- Replace with: Leave empty
- Search mode: `Regular expression`
- Click <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:** `^\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+\s+` finds digits at the start of a line followed by digits, colon, digits, a dot and spaces. When found, you replace them with nothing, thus removing them.

Comment: Oh my goodness, that worked like a champ !!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @JayStandley You can mark the question as answered. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)